# Automount USB pen drive and CDROM drive on plugin

Tags: linux, usb, mount, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry Pi and using Raspbian (without the GUI) and need USB pen drives to be mounted to /media/usb and cdrom drive to be mounted to /media/cdrom.

I have set up a script using autofs

/etc/auto.master

```
/media /etc/auto.media --timeout=2
```

/etc/auto.media

```
cdrom   -fstype=iso9660,ro,nosuid,nodev  :/dev/cdrom
usb     -fstype=vfat,rw,nosuid,nodev     :/dev/sda1
```

However it doesn't seem to be working, what would be the best method to have these auto mount? Or is there just something wrong with my scripts?

The pen drive is always `/dev/sda1` or at least `/dev/sda` but for my purposes it will always be the first partition, the memory card in a pi is `/dev/mmcblk0p1`

I have also checked that `autofs` is running.

Seems the respective folder in /media is not being created, and if i try to create it myself i get permission denied even as root.

`/media` permissions are:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2  root root 0
```

Comment: Is your useb drive always `/dev/sda1`? In fact, is it ever? That is usually the name of the 1st HDD, the memory card in a Pi I guess.

Comment: it is always /dev/sda1 or at least /dev/sda but for my purpose it will always be the first partition, the memory card in a pi is /dev/mmcblk0p1

Comment: OK, is the `autofs` service running? Check with `service autofs status`.

Comment: yes autofs is running

Comment: Seems the respective folder in /media is not being created, and if i try to create it myself i get permission denied even as root

Comment: That's strange. What are the permissions? Does it work if you try a different mountpoint? Anyway, could you update your question with the extra information (including the answers to my previous questions) instead of answering in comments please?

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0):

autofs doesn't actually attempt to mount media unless the mount point is accessed; you want something that will listen to attach notifications such as halevt or udevil.

Comment: could you expand on this?

Comment: In what way? autofs doesn't automatically mount, so find something that does.

Comment: Sorry, I just met do you have any experience with either halevt or udevil, and how I would set one of these up for what I require

Comment: I haven't used either, since I run X (along with the listener/mounter in the DE) on mine.

Answer (score 0):

Check udevil, it allows you to mount devices without need a password, also it comes with devmon wich is a daemon that watch for new devices beign plugged.

I'm using it with xmonad, and it's pretty cool, the best (only) and easy way that i found to do this.

So, for use udevil you just need to put as normal user:

udevil mount /dev/sb2

And for use devmon, wich is what you need something like:

```
devmon&
```

Also you can tell devmon what to do when something is mounted or unmounted:

```
devmon --exec-on-drive     "spacefm %d" \
   --exec-on-disc          "spacefm %d" \
   --exec-on-video         "vlc --verbose=-1 dvd://%f" \
   --exec-on-audio         "vlc --verbose=-1 cdda://%f" \
   --exec-on-unmount       "notify-send Device %f %l has been unmounted" \
   --exec-on-remove        "notify-send Device %f has been removed"
```

The [devmon](https://igurublog.wordpress.com/downloads/script-devmon/) reference.

The [udevil](http://ignorantguru.github.io/udevil/udevil--help.html) reference.

This guy has done a pretty awesome job, and there's spacefm wich is his FM.

Also there's another device mounter "ldm" it's not so fancy but is very light, just a 19.35kb of a c file, the repo is: LemonBoy/ldm  (i can't put more than two links).